# C error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, command, program-entry-point, exit-code

I'm new to C, I've already searched and I haven't found an answer, but I've been trying to get the program to give me a list with the name of the products typed in by the user followed by the sum of all prices and I've found the error:

```
clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
/tmp/main-7440c0.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to 'N'
main.c:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to 'Digitanome'
main.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to 'Lista'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
exit status 1
```

The code I've been trying is this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char (N[][40]);
int i;
char p;
int cod,cont, soma2;
char soma[100];

int Digitanome( char [][40], int );
void Lista( char [100][40], int );

typedef struct {
char produto[30];
char seçao [30];
float preco;
int cargo;
}Supermercado;

Supermercado compra;

    
int main(void)
{
  char Nome[100][40] = { '\0' };
  int qtdNomes = 0;

  soma2 = 0;
  do{  
    printf("\n\nEm qual seção está seu produto?");
    printf("\n1-Frutas \n2-Doces \n3-Material de Limpeza\n -->  ");
    scanf("%d",&cod);
    if(cod == 1){
      *compra.seçao = *strcpy(compra.seçao,"Frutas");
    }
    if(cod == 2){
      *compra.seçao = *strcpy(compra.seçao, "Doces");
    }
    if(cod == 3){
      *compra.seçao = *strcpy(compra.seçao,"Material de Limpeza");
    }
    int Digitanome(char N[][40], int i);
    {
      printf("Informe o produto que você quer nesta seção: \n");
      scanf("%s", & *N[i]);

      *compra.produto = Digitanome( Nome, qtdNomes );
      Lista( Nome, qtdNomes );
      return ++i;
    }
    return 0; 

    printf("Informe o preço do produto: \n");
    scanf("%f", &compra.preco);
    soma2 = soma2 + compra.preco;
    printf("\nDeseja mais algum produto? \n4-Sim \n0-Não, sair \n -->  ");
    scanf("%d",&cont);
  }while(cont == 4);
  {
    if (cont == 0)
      printf("\nFIM DAS COMPRAS!\n");

    void Lista(char p[100][40], int i);{
      int j = 0;
      for (; j < i; j++ )
        printf("\nSeus produtos são:%s\n", compra.produto);
    }
    printf("Essa compra está custando: %i \n", soma2);
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please start reading your error message from the top: `undefined reference to 'N'`

Comment: Where is `N` defined? You declare it as `external` but do not add any other compilation units besides `main.c`

Comment: Before, the error in "N" was `warning: tentative array definition assumed to have one element` and the only way to fix what they explained to me was to declare it as external, which generates the whole problem. Although before that, the problem with the other two names already existed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, it won't help to solve your particular errors. Please consult a general C programming guide before starting to code and learn how compilers, linkers, and include statements work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems:

1. `extern char (N[][40]);`

You declare `N` as `extern` without initialization so you would also need to delcare it in another module with initialization. But you don't actually ever use the variable `N`. You have `N[][40]` as an argument to `Digitanome`. Once you fix item numbers 2 and 3 below, you can remove `extern char (N[][40]);` completely.

2. You define `Digitanome` and `Lista` inside `main()`. You need to define them outside of `main()`.
3. You have semicolons at the end of `Digitanome` and `Lista` function definitions. You need to remove those.
4. You have code following the `return 0` statement.
5. You call `Digitanome` from inside `Digitanome`. That is probably not what you want.

Once you fix those problems, you will probably find more.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim mentioned, there is some syntax error in your code you need to fix.

I could not understand the logic of your code so if you still need help, comment to me so that we can do it together!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern char (N[][40]); int i; char p; int cod,cont, soma2; char soma[100];

int Digitanome( char [][40], int ); void Lista( char [100][40], int ); int qtdNomes = 0;

char Nome[100][40] = { '\0' };

typedef struct { char produto[30]; char seçao [30]; float preco; int cargo; }Supermercado;

Supermercado compra;

     int main(void) {

  soma2 = 0;   do{  
    printf("\n\nEm qual seção está seu produto?");
    printf("\n1-Frutas \n2-Doces \n3-Material de Limpeza\n -->  ");
    scanf("%d",&cod);
    if(cod == 1){
      *compra.seçao = *strcpy(compra.seçao,"Frutas");
    }
    if(cod == 2){
      *compra.seçao = *strcpy(compra.seçao, "Doces");
    }
    if(cod == 3){
      *compra.seçao = *strcpy(compra.seçao,"Material de Limpeza");
    }
    
    return 0; 

    printf("Informe o preço do produto: \n");
    scanf("%f", &compra.preco);
    soma2 = soma2 + compra.preco;
    printf("\nDeseja mais algum produto? \n4-Sim \n0-Não, sair \n -->  ");
    scanf("%d",&cont);   }while(cont == 4);   {
    if (cont == 0)
      printf("\nFIM DAS COMPRAS!\n");


    printf("Essa compra está custando: %i \n", soma2);   } }

int Digitanome(char N[][40], int i)
    {
      printf("Informe o produto que você quer nesta seção: \n");
      scanf("%s", & *N[i]);

      *compra.produto = Digitanome( Nome, qtdNomes );
      Lista( Nome, qtdNomes );
      return ++i;
    }

void Lista(char p[100][40], int i) {   int j = 0;   for (; j < i; j++ )
    printf("\nSeus produtos são:%s\n", compra.produto); }
```